# hide table with clicking button

Tags: jquery

I can show a table with a link label with following codes with jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#show").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").show();
    });
});
```

but when i want to do this for a button it will show the table for a second then it will be hidden. these are the codes for the button :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").show();
    });
});
```

Update :

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#table").hide();
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").show();
    });

});
```

Here are the codes :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#table").hide();
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").show();
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="#" id="show">Show</a> <a href="#" id="hide">Hide</a></p>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Show" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
</form>
<table width="515" border="0" class="table1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <td width="509" class="table1"><img src="Image/Tulips.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="Tulips" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please make a demo, such as on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/RMxq4/

Comment: Post more of your code. Something else is going on that you're not showing us.

Comment: @aquinas see the update. it has a picture in the table

Comment: `("#table").show();` I doubt this is your code either. You are missing a $ before your table.show. As Jared said, create a jsfiddle showing your ACTUAL code.

Comment: As @hayk.mart demonstrated, what you've shown *works*. Here is the updated fiddle (with the syntax error on the `$.show()` line fixed): http://jsfiddle.net/RMxq4/1/ Note, do not use `$.ready()` to set `display: none` unless you absolutely have to; use a CSS selector instead. **EDIT** - That `$.hide()` line in there could actually be causing the flash you're talking about, which is why you should not use it.

Comment: Is your button posting back to the server by any chance? Any you are getting a brand new dom perhaps?

Comment: Why are you using a `button` in a `form` that's `input type=submit`? That's the problem. Just use a `button id="button"`.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/73ctd/1 Unless that `button` is meant to submit a form at some point, you don't *need* the `form` tag.

Comment: Just like I thought, you're posting back to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works just fine, maybe what you ment is a `toggle` here you go: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUXyx/)

I just changed `.show()` into [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").toggle();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
The problam is that you using `type="submit"` on your button which causes the form to get submitted... change it to `type="button"`

**Another way** (that keeps the `type="submit"` there):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#table").hide();
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").show();
        return false;           
    });

});
```

I added `return false;` to prevent the button default action.

Comment: than there must be a problam with the rest of your code, because this part is fine - show us all of your code.

Comment: Devil's always in the details... It's an unannounced `form` and `input type=submit` situation. And, um, the `form` tag should probably also be jettisoned.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table:hidden").show();
        $("#table:visible").hide();
    });
});
```

or alternatively:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").toggle();
    });
});
```

**EDIT** As specified in your comment:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").show();
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("#table").hide();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

The table will appear for 2000ms (2 sec) and hide afterwards.

Comment: I think what @aliboy38 is describing in that comment above this one is the behavior that is unwanted, not how to get it. To wit: The `#button` is a submit for a form tag. Hence, the "it shows for a second then hides again". Because the page is reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Just use these the if statement here.

0"> and then your table tags go here. 
We can use the above javascript, however, If the submit button has got some action to do it wont know which action to be called.. to hide table or to perform the task given after submitting the button. So use the above if statement. It worked like a charm for me ! :)